# How to sum objects properties inside objects?

Tags: javascript, string, function, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to sum the total of matches and participants of each cup in this object:

```
{
    "Cup_1": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 3,
            "participants": 289
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 20,
            "participants": 1874
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 35,
            "participants": 3227
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 3,
            "participants": 294
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 5,
            "participants": 482
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 6,
            "participants": 574
        }
    },
    "Cup_2": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 17,
            "participants": 1609
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 46,
            "participants": 4408
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 157,
            "participants": 14391
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 0,
            "participants": 0
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 5,
            "participants": 469
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 10,
            "participants": 959
        }
    },
    "Cup_3": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 35,
            "participants": 3358
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 96,
            "participants": 9069
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 313,
            "participants": 29527
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 10,
            "participants": 960
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 16,
            "participants": 1538
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 45,
            "participants": 4280
        }
    },
    "Cup_4": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 2,
            "participants": 187
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 8,
            "participants": 742
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 37,
            "participants": 3416
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 0,
            "participants": 0
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 2,
            "participants": 196
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 3,
            "participants": 290
        }
    },
    "Cup_5": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 89,
            "participants": 1638
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to sum properties when the object has another object inside it (sorry I didn't learned that yet);

I want to have a new object with the results of each cup total matches, and total participants.
And also the total matches and participants of each category for all the cups except the cup_5 because it only have a single category.

Something like:

Cup_1 total matches: 72

Cup_1 total participants: 6740

Total Bronze matches (All cups): 57;

Total Bronze Participants (All cups): 5443

Example new object with the results:

```
var cups_result = {
  "Total_Cup_1": {
    matches: 72,
    participants: 6740,
  },
  "Total_Bronze": {
    matches: 57,
    participants: 5443,
  },
}
```

I read that this sum of objects properties could be done with `.map` but I don't know how to properly use map with objects.

If anyone could be kind to help me I would be grateful!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question to reflect that I am trying to sum objects properties inside objects!

Comment: I don't know how to access the objects like "bronze", "silver" and so, to get the total vaues.

Comment: @RogerHN use for in statement to loop over the Key of an object.

Comment: I tried this: `for (var c in cups){
    console.log(c)
  }`
but it only logs the names of each object like `"Cup_1"`

Comment: Nested for loop might help in this case. for (var c in cups){ for ( let medal in cups[c] ) { console.log(cups[c][medal][""matches"], cups[c][medal]["participants"] ) } }

Comment: You can easily enumerate all properties of an object using the Object.entries(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE) function. This will give you an array of arrays which are key-value pairs. Going from this you should be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: @JakubRusilko Yeah but this seems to complicate even more the result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still separate the totals per cup from the totals per medal, and maybe add a grand total as well (since we are at it):

```js
const data = {"Cup_1": {"bronze": {"matches": 3,"participants": 289},"silver": {"matches": 20,"participants": 1874},"gold": {"matches": 35,"participants": 3227},"platinum": {"matches": 3,"participants": 294},"diamond": {"matches": 5,"participants": 482},"ace": {"matches": 6,"participants": 574}},"Cup_2": {"bronze": {"matches": 17,"participants": 1609},"silver": {"matches": 46,"participants": 4408},"gold": {"matches": 157,"participants": 14391},"platinum": {"matches": 0,"participants": 0},"diamond": {"matches": 5,"participants": 469},"ace": {"matches": 10,"participants": 959}},"Cup_3": {"bronze": {"matches": 35,"participants": 3358},"silver": {"matches": 96,"participants": 9069},"gold": {"matches": 313,"participants": 29527},"platinum": {"matches": 10,"participants": 960},"diamond": {"matches": 16,"participants": 1538},"ace": {"matches": 45,"participants": 4280}},"Cup_4": {"bronze": {"matches": 2,"participants": 187},"silver": {"matches": 8,"participants": 742},"gold": {"matches": 37,"participants": 3416},"platinum": {"matches": 0,"participants": 0},"diamond": {"matches": 2,"participants": 196},"ace": {"matches": 3,"participants": 290}},"Cup_5": {"bronze": {"matches": 89,"participants": 1638}}}

const cupTotals = {}, 
      medalTotals = {}, 
      grandTotal = { matches: 0, participants: 0 };
for (const cup in data) {
    cupTotals[cup] = { matches: 0, participants: 0 };
    for (let medal in data[cup]) {
        const {matches, participants} = data[cup][medal];
        if (cup === "Cup_5" && medal === "bronze") medal = "junior";
        cupTotals[cup].matches += matches;
        cupTotals[cup].participants += participants;
        if (!medalTotals[medal]) medalTotals[medal] = { matches: 0, participants: 0 };
        medalTotals[medal].matches += matches;
        medalTotals[medal].participants += participants;
        grandTotal.matches += matches;
        grandTotal.participants += participants;
    }
}
const results = { cupTotals, medalTotals, grandTotal };

console.log(results);
```

Comment: That's even better, thank you a lot too! I will try here and try to understand how this function works! I have some serious difficulties in understanding objects and arrays manipulations.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask about pieces of code that need clarification.

Comment: In this function it's possible to exclude the "Cup_5" from the sum?

Comment: Sure, what is special about Cup_5 if I may ask?

Comment: It's a junior category, with a single medal (that I represented with bronze too, but it's not a bronze medal).

Comment: OK, I updated the code for that, and added a grant total as well. Cup_5 is completely ignored from all statistics.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make logic to produce a statistic on a "junior" medal when it is Cat_5. Would that be any better? If so, I'll add the code for that...

Comment: Of course it will, If not I will be doing it by hand :)

Comment: Also, you just blew my mind with this function! It's perfect, the exact result that I was looking for. I will study piece by piece to understand it more! I didn't knew the `continue` statement, only the `break` (I am starting second year of university on IT).

Comment: Now modified it to take Cat_5 into account, but changing "bronze" to "junior" on the fly. Let me know what you think. If worse, I will revert the change of course ;)

Comment: Even better, you sir deserve a medal! Thank you very much for helping me solve this! Learned a lot with your logic!

Comment: your code is n't generic for any kind of medal as it specifically tests for `if value == 'bronze etc' ..`

Comment: @GauravSaraswat, please read the comments above. This  `if` is there to deal with a very particular need the OP expressed here. Without it, it works fine also.

Answer (score 2):

Nested for loop will be helpful in fetching the matches and participants fields from cups var.

```
for (var c in cups) { 
   for ( let medal in cups[c] ) { 
        console.log(cups[c][medal]["matches"], cups[c][medal]["participants"]);
   } 
}
```

Comment: This works, I have access to the data, but how to sum them all like I said in the question? That's the problem :(

Comment: @RogerHN "+" is used to sum two numbers in javascript. I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty object for result.Then use `forEach()` to loop though all cups. And store result in the empty object.

```js
let data = {
    "Cup_1": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 3,
            "participants": 289
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 20,
            "participants": 1874
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 35,
            "participants": 3227
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 3,
            "participants": 294
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 5,
            "participants": 482
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 6,
            "participants": 574
        }
    },
    "Cup_2": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 17,
            "participants": 1609
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 46,
            "participants": 4408
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 157,
            "participants": 14391
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 0,
            "participants": 0
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 5,
            "participants": 469
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 10,
            "participants": 959
        }
    },
    "Cup_3": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 35,
            "participants": 3358
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 96,
            "participants": 9069
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 313,
            "participants": 29527
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 10,
            "participants": 960
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 16,
            "participants": 1538
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 45,
            "participants": 4280
        }
    },
    "Cup_4": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 2,
            "participants": 187
        },
        "silver": {
            "matches": 8,
            "participants": 742
        },
        "gold": {
            "matches": 37,
            "participants": 3416
        },
        "platinum": {
            "matches": 0,
            "participants": 0
        },
        "diamond": {
            "matches": 2,
            "participants": 196
        },
        "ace": {
            "matches": 3,
            "participants": 290
        }
    },
    "Cup_5": {
        "bronze": {
            "matches": 89,
            "participants": 1638
        }
    }
}



function sumOfCup(obj,cupNos,cuptypes){
  let result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(a => {
    Object.keys(obj[a]).forEach(x => {
    if(result[`Total_${x}`]){
      result[`Total_${x}`].matches += obj[a][x].matches;
      result[`Total_${x}`].participants += obj[a][x].participants;
    }
    else result[`Total_${x}`] = {...obj[a][x]};
  })
  result[`Total_${a}`] = Object.values(obj[a]).reduce((ac,a)=>{
    ac.matches += a.matches 
    ac.participants += a.participants;
    return ac;
  },{matches:0,participants:0})
  })

  
 
  return result
  
  
  
}
console.log(data);
console.log(sumOfCup(data))
```

Comment: Holy! This is some serious complex function! I don't know how to write things like that yet! I will try here and try to understand how it works! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys`, `Object.values` and destructuring for this - the below returns a summary of each cup:

```js
const cup_data = {
  "Cup_1": {
    "bronze": {
      "matches": 3,
      "participants": 289
    },
    "silver": {
      "matches": 20,
      "participants": 1874
    },
    "gold": {
      "matches": 35,
      "participants": 3227
    },
    "platinum": {
      "matches": 3,
      "participants": 294
    },
    "diamond": {
      "matches": 5,
      "participants": 482
    },
    "ace": {
      "matches": 6,
      "participants": 574
    }
  },
  "Cup_2": {
    "bronze": {
      "matches": 17,
      "participants": 1609
    },
    "silver": {
      "matches": 46,
      "participants": 4408
    },
    "gold": {
      "matches": 157,
      "participants": 14391
    },
    "platinum": {
      "matches": 0,
      "participants": 0
    },
    "diamond": {
      "matches": 5,
      "participants": 469
    },
    "ace": {
      "matches": 10,
      "participants": 959
    }
  },
  "Cup_3": {
    "bronze": {
      "matches": 35,
      "participants": 3358
    },
    "silver": {
      "matches": 96,
      "participants": 9069
    },
    "gold": {
      "matches": 313,
      "participants": 29527
    },
    "platinum": {
      "matches": 10,
      "participants": 960
    },
    "diamond": {
      "matches": 16,
      "participants": 1538
    },
    "ace": {
      "matches": 45,
      "participants": 4280
    }
  },
  "Cup_4": {
    "bronze": {
      "matches": 2,
      "participants": 187
    },
    "silver": {
      "matches": 8,
      "participants": 742
    },
    "gold": {
      "matches": 37,
      "participants": 3416
    },
    "platinum": {
      "matches": 0,
      "participants": 0
    },
    "diamond": {
      "matches": 2,
      "participants": 196
    },
    "ace": {
      "matches": 3,
      "participants": 290
    }
  },
  "Cup_5": {
    "bronze": {
      "matches": 89,
      "participants": 1638
    }
  }
};

let cup_results = {};
Object.keys(cup_data).forEach(key => {
  let newCupKey = "Total_" + key;
  cup_results[newCupKey] = {};
  cup_results[newCupKey].matches = Object.values(cup_data[key]).reduce((acc, {
    matches
  }) => acc + matches, 0);
  cup_results[newCupKey].participants = Object.values(cup_data[key]).reduce((acc, {
    participants
  }) => acc + participants, 0);
});

console.log(cup_results);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribuition, it's another interesting function to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can, of course, make a monolithic function that will do everything you need, but it's probably going to be easier to understand and maintain if you break it down into smaller ideas.

For example you can make a function that only takes an object and returns the sum of `matches` and `participants`. That will be short, readable and, most importantly, reusable:

```
function sumObj(obj){
  // returns the sum of matches and participant propertes of all obj's values
  return Object.values(obj).reduce((sums, o) => {
    sums.matches += o.matches
    sums.participants += o.participants
    return sums
  }, {matches: 0, participants: 0})
}
```

Now you can use and reuse this function in a variety of ways. For example to get all the main categories of the larger object, just `reduce` over the values and set a new key for each obj:

```js
let o = {"Cup_1": {"bronze": {"matches": 3,"participants": 289},"silver": {"matches": 20,"participants": 1874},"gold": {"matches": 35,"participants": 3227},"platinum": {"matches": 3,"participants": 294},"diamond": {"matches": 5,"participants": 482},"ace": {"matches": 6,"participants": 574}},"Cup_2": {"bronze": {"matches": 17,"participants": 1609},"silver": {"matches": 46,"participants": 4408},"gold": {"matches": 157,"participants": 14391},"platinum": {"matches": 0,"participants": 0},"diamond": {"matches": 5,"participants": 469},"ace": {"matches": 10,"participants": 959}},"Cup_3": {"bronze": {"matches": 35,"participants": 3358},"silver": {"matches": 96,"participants": 9069},"gold": {"matches": 313,"participants": 29527},"platinum": {"matches": 10,"participants": 960},"diamond": {"matches": 16,"participants": 1538},"ace": {"matches": 45,"participants": 4280}},"Cup_4": {"bronze": {"matches": 2,"participants": 187},"silver": {"matches": 8,"participants": 742},"gold": {"matches": 37,"participants": 3416},"platinum": {"matches": 0,"participants": 0},"diamond": {"matches": 2,"participants": 196},"ace": {"matches": 3,"participants": 290}},"Cup_5": {"bronze": {"matches": 89,"participants": 1638}}}

/* 
 * Base function. Sum an object's matches & participants
 */
function sumObj(obj){
  return Object.values(obj).reduce((sums, o) => {
    sums.matches += o.matches
    sums.participants += o.participants
    return sums
  }, {matches: 0, participants: 0})
}

let sums = Object.entries(o).reduce((totals, [key, val]) => {
  totals[key] = sumObj(val) // call the sum function for each value
  return totals
}, {})
console.log(sums)

/* 
 * Pass sums back into the same function to get a grand total: 
 */
console.log("grand total: ", sumObj(sums))

/* 
 * To sum only a subset filter the obj entries first:
 * Without Cup_5 
 */
let minus_5 = Object.entries(o)
  .filter(([k, v ]) => k != 'Cup_5')  // filter first
  .reduce((totals, [key, val]) => {
      totals[key] = sumObj(val)       // call the sum function for each value
      return totals
}, {})
console.log("all but Cup_5", minus_5)

/* 
 * To get only a subcategory, use map and make a new
 * array and pass it to the function:
 * Only bronze:
 */ 
let bronze = Object.values(o).map(item => item.bronze)  // get only bronze
console.log("Bronze", sumObj(bronze))
```

As you should see this is very flexible and will let you create many different reports with the same core function.

Comment: Interesting way to solve too, I mentioned earlier that I read it could be done using `.map` and `.reduce`  but I never used this methods before, and didn't knew how it worked. Thank you for your contribuition, I will try to learn how to write that too. It looks more easy breaking it into smaller functions.

Comment: Good luck @RogerHN, as you can see from the answers, there are a lot of different ways to get to the same goal.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I like to ask questions here, people always show many ways to do it! I learn more everyday!

Answer (score 2):

I think below function should be generic solution to your problem.

```js
const data = {"Cup_1": {"bronze": {"matches": 3,"participants": 289},"silver": {"matches": 20,"participants": 1874},"gold": {"matches": 35,"participants": 3227},"platinum": {"matches": 3,"participants": 294},"diamond": {"matches": 5,"participants": 482},"ace": {"matches": 6,"participants": 574}},"Cup_2": {"bronze": {"matches": 17,"participants": 1609},"silver": {"matches": 46,"participants": 4408},"gold": {"matches": 157,"participants": 14391},"platinum": {"matches": 0,"participants": 0},"diamond": {"matches": 5,"participants": 469},"ace": {"matches": 10,"participants": 959}},"Cup_3": {"bronze": {"matches": 35,"participants": 3358},"silver": {"matches": 96,"participants": 9069},"gold": {"matches": 313,"participants": 29527},"platinum": {"matches": 10,"participants": 960},"diamond": {"matches": 16,"participants": 1538},"ace": {"matches": 45,"participants": 4280}},"Cup_4": {"bronze": {"matches": 2,"participants": 187},"silver": {"matches": 8,"participants": 742},"gold": {"matches": 37,"participants": 3416},"platinum": {"matches": 0,"participants": 0},"diamond": {"matches": 2,"participants": 196},"ace": {"matches": 3,"participants": 290}},"Cup_5": {"bronze": {"matches": 89,"participants": 1638}}};

function getCumlativeData(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((cumData, cup)=>{
    let cupCumlative = {matches: 0, participants:0};
     Object.keys(data[cup]).forEach(med => {
       cumData[`Total_${med}`] = cumData[`Total_${med}`] || {matches: 0, participants:0};
       cumData[`Total_${med}`] = {
         matches: cumData[`Total_${med}`].matches + data[cup][med].matches,
         participants: cumData[`Total_${med}`].participants + data[cup][med].participants,
       };
       cupCumlative = {
          matches: cupCumlative.matches +  data[cup][med].matches,
          participants: cupCumlative.participants +  data[cup][med].participants
       };
     });
     return {...cumData, [`Total_${cup}`]: cupCumlative};
  },{});
}

console.log(getCumlativeData(data));
```